# Bitcoin Private Key

Tags: bitcoind

Are there any particular methods for computing the private key corresponding to an arbitrary bitcoin address? For example, I want to find the private key for this address to access the funds:     1KsFhYKLs8qb1GHqrPxHoywNQpet2CtP9t

Comment: There is a reason it is called a ***private key***: because no one else can possibly figure out what it is; and if they could, they could take all your money.

Comment: [That address](https://blockchain.info/address/1KsFhYKLs8qb1GHqrPxHoywNQpet2CtP9t) has been very busy, recently transferring $35,000 in and out.  Clearly, *someone* knows the private key.

Answer (score 1):

The whole strength of the Bitcoin protocol is that the private key is inaccessible. Period!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is one of the fundamental properties of digital signing algorithms that you cannot derive the private key from the public key (or the address which is a derivative of the public key). Without this property, digital signing would be pointless, as anyone could fake any signature.

The irreversibility of address derivation from the private key is one of the main security assumptions of the Bitcoin system.

Answer (score 0):

The question was about any methods.
Brute-forcing the key is one of them. But that will take many many years. Millions of years.